# visual studio 2010 code optimization tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

what are tools in vs 2010 for helping in code optimization?. Can i find out the execution time of the line of code i wrote and then improve it based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Visual Studio Profiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/)

- [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)
- [Analyzing Application Performance by Using Profiling Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx)
- [CPU Performance Counters in Visual Studio 2010 Profiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2010/06/22/cpu-performance-counters-in-visual-studio-2010-profiler.aspx)
- [Windows Performance Analysis Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default)
- [Optimizing Your Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz7ttk5s.aspx)
- [Tips for Improving Time-Critical Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eye126ky.aspx)

Third party products:

- [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)
- [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)